# How does windows handling of timeout after SetCommTimeouts unfold?

Tags: c, windows, serial-port, uart

How does windows handling of timeout after SetCommTimeouts unfold?
Does it do reconnect at that level or do I in the app layer?

Comment: "_...do I in the app layer?"_ Do I _what_ in the app layer?  Your question lacks clarity.  It does what the documentation states - if you are in any doubt create an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are assuming a TCP/IP session, but there is no such concept in the serial port API.

A serial port is a peer-to-peer physically connected cable that allows communication if the program opens the port at both ends.
Set the timeout separately for several Read/Write factors. See the API documentation for more details.

For both Read/Write timeout values, when you call the Read/Write API, you will be notified that a Read/Write API timeout error has occurred if the specified number of bytes of data cannot be sent or received within the specified time.

Even if those errors occur, the connections between the ports are maintained and there is no concept or API to reconnect at the serial port API level.

The programmer should consider whether a program has been created that conforms to the communication setting conditions and protocol specifications of the connected device, not to close/re-open when there is an error, for example.

Depending on the protocol specifications of the device, those errors may simply be that there is no data to notify, or that something is running and not ready to receive data.

In that case, simply repeat Read/Write until it is valid.

Other devices may have strict state transitions defined by something like a finite state automaton, with command/response/error handling specifications.

Therefore, your question asked without specifying the connected device is meaningless.